# How to resolve instance of base interface with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have an interface that inherits from another one

```
public interface ISpecificHandler : IHandler
```

With Simple Injector I register my type and implementation

```
container.RegisterSingleton<ISpecificHandler, SpecificHandlerImpl>();
```

But how can I just resolve `IHandler` instead of `ISpecificHandler`?

```
//Expect SpecificHandlerImpl as handler
IHandler handler = ServiceLocator.GetInstance<IHandler>(); //error
```

This throws a `InvalidOperationException` that the IHandler type is not registered

Comment: Why do you want to do this? How many `IHandler` implementations do you have?

Comment: This is just an example scenario. Anyway, I could have multiple implementations. If I can cast a `SpecificHandlerImpl` to `IHandler` why not also resolve them through an IOC container!?

Comment: "why not also resolve them through an IOC container!?". Because that easily leads to ambiguity in your code and design. Without being more specific, nobody can really advice you about what is the best way to solve this. So I suggest posting the complete `IHandler` and `ISpecificHandler` definitions, describe how many other implementations you have and show some example of how you expect this `IHandler` to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several solutions, but it really depends on what your application really needs. Here are some suggestions.

You just register the implementation twice:

```
container.Register<IHandler, SpecificHandlerImpl>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<ISpecificHandler, SpecificHandlerImpl>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

But perhaps you want to resolve multiple handlers, in which case you will have to probably register them as a collection:

```
var reg1 = Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<SpecificHandlerImpl>();
var reg2 = Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<AnotherHandlerImpl>();

container.RegisterCollection<IHandler>(new[] { reg1, reg2 });
```

You might run into troubles however when using a non-generic `IHandler` interface, because you will usually have one specific implementation that should be executed in a certain scenario (in other words, you might be violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). So you'd often be better of using a generic `IHandler<T>` abstraction where `T` is a parameter object that contains the values of the handler. In that case there is always a one-to-one mapping between a closed `IHandler<T>` and an implementation. [This article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) gives a good explanation of the advantages of such design.

But without knowing the problem you're trying to solve, it's hard to say what would be the right solution for you.

Comment: Thanks Steven, right now I'm new to IOC container and SimpleInjector. The provided code is just part of a trial project to get to know the SimpleInjector specifics. But now I realized that this behavior isn't implementation specific but to prevent uncertainty